# Why are the outputs different if i include parenthesis

Tags: java, casting, parentheses

Hi i'm just wondering why

```
System.out.println((double) 1/4);
```

prints out 0.25

but

```
System.out.println((double) (1/4));
```

prints out 0.0

Comment: with the parenthesis, it first executes 1/4, with both of them being ints, then you cast the result to double. without them, you first cast 1 to a double, then execute the division

Comment: [Integer Division](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685450/why-is-the-result-of-1-3-0)

Answer (score 9):

The former first casts `1` to `double`, then does a floating-point division.

The latter first performs `(1/4)` as integer division and only then converts the result to `double`.

The rule in Java is that if both operands are integers, the operation is integer division; if any of the operands is float, it's floating-point division.

Answer (score 4):

The expression `(double) 1/4` is equal to `((double) 1)/4`. That is, it converts the integer value `1` to the floating point value `1.0`, and divides that floating point value with `4`, resulting in `0.25`.

The expression `(double) (1/4)` first does the division, using integers. That results in the integer value `0` which is then converted to a `double`.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure either 1 or 4 is double . Declaration :

var numerator = 1.0